# Chai function not found

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm just getting started with TDD, and I'm running into an odd issue. I've written a very simple test for a (also simple) `user` module. For some reason, the test complains that the `hasOwnProperty` function does not exist.

Test code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var user = require('./user');

describe('Name', function() {
  it('Should have a name', function() {
    expect(user).to.have.ownProperty('name');
  });
  it('The name property should be a string', function () {
    expect(user.name).to.be.a('string');
  });
  it('Should have non empty string as name', function () {
    expect(user.name).to.have.length.above(0);
  });
});
```

Module:

```
var user = Object.create(null);

user.name = 'Name';

// exports
module.exports = user;
```

After running `$ mocha test.js`, the first test fails. 
[Chai ownProperty reference](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_ownproperty)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Console output:

```
Name
  1) Should have a name
  ✓ The name property should be a string
  ✓ Should have non empty string as name


2 passing (12ms)
1 failing

1) Name Should have a name:
   TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at Assertion.assertOwnProperty (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:937:13)
    at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as ownProperty] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:6:26)
```

Comment: post your console log pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create(null)` means that the prototype used to create the object user is null, hence it does not inherit the properties of the 'Object' type.

Try this instead.

```
var user = Object.create({});

user.name = 'Name';

 // exports
module.exports = user;
```

You will need to use `Object.create({})`, to have access to `hasOwnProperty` method.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing response! I did have 1 q however: how do you know that the `ownProperty` function actually maps to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`? I thought it was just a function provided by Chai

Comment: Well, Chai is just a testing library, it still needs access to the Javascript Object prototype to establish whether a property is an `ownProperty`. There is no other way to check if a property is an ownProperty.